# Lock the nativity of the QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, python-2.7, pyqt

How to lock the nativity of the QGIS using PyQGIS

```
icon = QtGui.QIcon(folPath + '\Dsmsoft.png')

pixmap = icon.pixmap(302, 302, QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)              
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(pixmap, QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
self.dlg.setWindowIcon(icon)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "lock the nativity"? Nativity means birth.

Comment: created new plugin,but after using other plugin functionalities like select,measure and coming back to my plugin without clicking it once again,just by working with layers.(simply by saying coming back to plugin from where we left instead of by going to the beginning)